# Como fazer com que o formulário atualize corretamente?

Tags: thread, delphi-xe3, label, panel

Tenho uma tela no delphi que é atualizada constantemente, é utilizada junto com uma catraca, toda vez que uma pessoa coloca a digital ou digita a senha, essa tela é atualizada com as informações desta pessoa.

A chamada para atualização vem de uma **TThread.Synchronize**. Antes estava utilizando o **TForm.Repaint** após a atualização para que ele redesenhasse os componentes atualizados. O problema é que utilizando o repaint direto do formulário, ele redesenhava o formulário inteiro, inclusive os componentes que não foram atualizados, e apresentava um erro de **GDI** que não consegui encontrar solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, tirei essa função e estou utilizando o **repaint** nos componentes que são atualizados.

Após limpar a tela, ou atualizar as informações, estou utilizando:

```
pnlVencimento.Repaint
pnlAluno.Repaint
pnlStatus.Repaint
```

Todos esses são painéis contém labels dentro deles. Todos são atualizados normalmente no começo, mas após algumas horas, os painéis ficam **preto** e não são mais atualizados.

Segue imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]